# How to get client PC details using browser?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to get client pc-name and current login username using my asp.net MVC application for some security purposes.

I tried many ways but got nothing.

```
var UserDeatils = Request.LogonUserIdentity;

string MachineName1 = Environment.MachineName;                            
string MachineName2 = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();                            
string MachineName3 = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"].ToString();
string MachineName4 = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUERNAME");

var PCName1 = Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]).HostName;

string PCName2 = (UserDeatils.UserClaims.First().Value).Substring(0, (UserDeatils.Name.ToString()).IndexOf("\\"));
string PCName3 = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"]).HostName;
string PCName4 = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
string PCName5 = User.Identity.Name;
string PCName6 = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_PORT"].ToString();
string PCName7 = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"].ToString();
string PCName8 = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].ToString();
```

Is there an option to collect this data?

Comment: I'm not a web application expert, but I would be seriously alarmed if any of that would work. That's personal information the browser must not provide to the server.

Comment: Also; I cannot see how this information can be used for "security purposes" as it is easy to fake.

Comment: you cannot get the client's PC name from your asp.net core application. Environment variables are variables pertaining only your hosted site. you can only get things like browser name, IP, device type (mobile or PC in some cases)

Comment: You can somehow get the Windows Logon information I believe, but otherwise there's no difference for the browser whether you browse an internal or an external site.

Comment: @PMF, I agree with you, but this is our company ERP, so I thought about it and with Formula12's suggestion I decided to check user login from PC or mobile. It doesn't quite work for me, but it's doable for now. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @Formula12 with your suggestion I decided to check user login from PC or mobile. It doesn't quite work for me, but it's work for now. Thanks for the information

Comment: @KlausGütter. This application is used by our company as ERP. We want to know if our user is only logging in using our company computers. That's what I meant by "security purposes". Our company branches are located in two countries. We don't use domain or vpn yet. Anyway Thanks For the Informations.

Comment: You cannot directly get that information from the browser as this can be exploited by malicious websites easily, the most you can get is that you use a domain, change the web app authentication to windows and access the current user's logon, groups, etc. And again, for that you need an active directory implementation.